# assign value within destructuring bracket?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am familiar with the concept of destructuring... Aka:

```
const { name } = student // assigns a variable named name with the value of student.name
```

However, I was confused today when I saw what looks like assignment inside of destructuring? Aka:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {tabs = [{name : null}]} = props;

    const firstTab = tabs[0];

    this.state = {
        currentTab : firstTab.name
    } ;
}
```

I don't understand this part, `const { tabs = [{name : null}] } = props`. Can someone help explain this syntax?

Comment: its called assigning inside of destructuring. You are setting a default value to tabs to be an array with one item in it. an object that has a key called `name`

Comment: It’s destructuring with a default value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2

Comment: @jonrsharpe why not `const {tabs = null} = props `?

Comment: Because they didn’t want the default value to be `null`? They wanted it to be the value that they’ve set.

Comment: because tabs would then be null.. and the following line `tabs[0]` would blow up?

Comment: @AlisaTMorgan you didnt listen to what we were saying or didnt understand what we said. when this javascript runs, `JSON.stringify(tabs)` would print out `[{name : null}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a fancy way of setting default value of tabs to `[ { name: null } ]`, when `props` has no property `tabs`

#### Example:

```
// When props.tabs === undefiend
let props = { param1: "param1" };
let { tabs = [{ name : null }] } = props;
console.log(tabs); // returns [{ name: null }]

// when props.tabs !== undefined
let props = { tabs: [{name: "param2"}, {name: "param3"}] };
let { tabs = [{ name : null }]} = props;
console.log(tabs) // returns [{name: "param2"}, {name: "param3"}]
```

The nice thing about this default value assignment, is it makes for less buggy code. When the next line of code runs e.g. `const firstTab = tabs[0];` `tabs[0]` would blow up if you didn't setup the default assignment.

Comment: I got it but in the consturctor why not do `this.state = {
        currentTab : null 
    }`?

Comment: @AlisaTMorgan then it should be `if(tabs) ... else ...` - depending if there are `props.tabs`. Cannot say it's significant improvement rather different approaches. Especially me would use `defaultProps` as most explicit way.